# How do I attach a GPU to a Google Cloud build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to run a CI/CD on my codebase, but in order to run my tests, I need a GPU-enabled VM (to produce deep learning results).

However, the only configurable machine option I see is the machine type (number of cores and memory). I don't see an option for adding an accelerator type (GPU).

Is there a way to attach a GPU to the build VM, and if not, is there another method for triggering a test on another GPU enabled VM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Cloud Build doesn't provide machine types equipped with GPUs at the moment. One option though is to use the [remote-builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/remote-builder) cloud builder. It allows you to run your builds on a Compute Engine instances running in your project. You can use the `INSTANCE_ARGS` option to customize the instance to fit your specific needs, adding one or more GPUs in this case. You can have a look [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/remote-builder/examples/test-configs) for some example configs. You can use any flag available with the `gcloud compute instances create` [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create), including the `--accelerator` flag for GPUs.

Comment: A bit late on that one but if it can help :)